# Rounding milliseconds in Pandas datettime column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe in which one column has datetime data. The format of the timestamps is like

`2020-05-05 12:15:33.500000`

I want to format/ round the milliseconds to the first decimal point. I am using the following code to format.

```
df['timestamp'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')
```

Is there any modification I can do to round the milliseconds? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @9769953  nop it returns, 2020-05-05 12:15:%.1f

Comment: what's wrong with `.dt.round('s')` or `.dt.floor('s')` or `.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`?

Comment: oh, sorry, I see you want the first digit of the fractional second part. Also, `df['timestamp'].dt.round('100ms')` almost works but shows `.100`, `.200`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly. You can however post process it with slicing:

```
df['timestamp'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f').str[:-5]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are specifically interested in **rounding** (not merely truncating down), your Series to the nearest tenth of a second, then:

to Timestamps:

```py
df['timestamp'].dt.round('100ms')  # still a Series of Timestamps
```

To get a Series of strings (with controlled format) instead of Timestamps, then apply one of the other answers to the above, e.g.:

```py
df['timestamp'].dt.round('100ms').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').str[:-5]
```

Or, faster (between 5x for short Series and 1.6x for 100K values or more):

```py
df['timestamp'].apply(lambda t: t.round('100ms').strftime(
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-5])
```

#### Example

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'timestamp': pd.to_datetime([
        '2022-08-18 15:30:00.440000',
        '2022-08-18 15:30:00.46000',
        '2022-08-18 15:30:00.500000',
    ])
})

>>> df
                timestamp
0 2022-08-18 15:30:00.440
1 2022-08-18 15:30:00.460
2 2022-08-18 15:30:00.500

>>> df['timestamp'].dt.round('100ms')
0   2022-08-18 15:30:00.400
1   2022-08-18 15:30:00.500
2   2022-08-18 15:30:00.500
Name: timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]

>>> df['timestamp'].dt.round('100ms').dt.strftime(
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').str[:-5]
0    2022-08-18 15:30:00.4
1    2022-08-18 15:30:00.5
2    2022-08-18 15:30:00.5
Name: timestamp, dtype: object

>>> df['timestamp'].apply(lambda t: t.round('100ms').strftime(
...     '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-5])
0    2022-08-18 15:30:00.4
1    2022-08-18 15:30:00.5
2    2022-08-18 15:30:00.5
Name: timestamp, dtype: object
```

Comment: Yes, very true, I should have added this ;)

Comment: This is a great answer and should be rated highest, as rounding is very important.

Answer (score 1):

Slight modification of @mozway's answer:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 18, 10, 42, 37, 714473)
>>> dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')[:-5]
'2022-08-18 10:42:37:7'
```